# Connecting a Control of Tools to another Form (void)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

i already worked on connecting a tool control to another1 using this code:

--- **Form1.cs**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 frm = new Form2(this);
            frm.Show();
        }

        public string LabelText
        {
            get { return Lbl.Text; }
            set { Lbl.Text = value; }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

**--- Form2.cs**

```
  public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private Form1 mainForm = null;
        public Form2(Form callingForm)
        {
            mainForm = callingForm as Form1;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }



        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.mainForm.LabelText = txtMessage.Text;

            if (timer1.Enabled == true)
            {
                int line = 1 + richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine());
                int column = 1 + richTextBox1.SelectionStart - richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine();
                txtMessage.Text = "line: " + line.ToString() + " , column: " + column.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

***** output was**

[image]

text of label from Form2 was connected into Form1 .

so its already fixed .

now my problem was is there a way i can do the same way for void function?

*i mean for example:
in Form1, i got 1button with a control inside of:
richTextBox1.Copy();
then this control will be for  richTextBox1 on Form2 .
(which will copy the selected text in richtextbox on Form2)
is that possible? really need a help .thanks a lot in advance!*

Comment: @Elegiac We want to help but we don't understand what you're asking. What does **i got 1button with a control inside of: richTextBox1.Copy();** mean? Do you mean you have that code in the Button's event-handler? (The code with: **private void timer1_Tick...** is called an event-handler, not a Control. A Button is a Control, and so is a RichTextBox.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd move your declaration of Form2 out to Class level:

**--Form1**

```
    Form2 frm = null;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm = new Form2(this);
        frm.Show();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (frm != null)
        {
            frm.CopyRichTextBox();
        }
    }
```

**--Form2**

```
    public void CopyRichTextBox()
    {
        this.richTextBox1.Copy();
    }
```

Comment: no sir what i want was i want to transfer the control of button (richTextBox1.Copy();) that controls the richtextbox on form2

Comment: sir pls read the italic text above thats what i want to do :( thanks .

Comment: I've read the italic text above.  That's what this code does.  Button2, which is in Form1, allows you to copy the SelectedText from the RichTextBox that is in Form2.

Comment: ill post result infew minutes

Comment: sir can it be  if (frm != null)
            {
                frm.RichTextBoxSelectedText.Copy();
            } ? i dont need the Lbl.Text to be the text of RichTextBox . i just want the richtextbox to have a copy command . but its error was No overload for method 'Copy' takes 0 arguments

Comment: Gotcha...I understand now.  Updated the code above.  Now when you hit button2 in Form1, the selected text in the richTextBox1 on Form2 will be placed on the clipboard.

Comment: sir its not working :/ pls sed me a sample project that worked coz it has an error object reference not set to an instance of an object. pointing the richTextBox1.Copy();

Comment: `richTextBox1.Copy();` is in Form2.  Does Form2 have a RichTextBox called `richTextBox1` on it?

Comment: yeah pls give me a sample project sir @Idle_Mind

Answer (score 1):

Here's something to get you started:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2(this);            
    }
}
```

And make sure that `richTextBox1` is declared `public`.

And:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 sendingForm;

    public Form2(Form1 frm1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        sendingForm = frm1;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Text = sendingForm.richTextBox1.Text;
    }
}
```

What's done here is: Initializing the `Form2` instance with a reference to the sender `Form1` instance, and using that reference to get to the `RichTextBox`.

EDIT:

Maybe (!) this is what you're looking for:

```
mainForm.richTextBox1.Copy();
```

Comment: no sir what i want was i want to transfer the control of button (richTextBox1.Copy();) that controls the richtextbox on form2

Comment: sir pls read the italic text above thats what i want to do :( thanks

Comment: @Elegiac What you wrote is either in incorrect English or you're calling 'Control' something which is really called something else. I edited my answer by what _might_ be what you're looking for. The line I wrote will be in Form2, but will copy the text of **Form1's** richTextBox1 to the clipboard.

Comment: @Elegiac That's very strange. I don't understand why.

Comment: @Elegiac Are you using Silverlight by any chance? (I just searched and saw that it doesn't contain a `Copy` method.)

Comment: i think because he richtextbox was not declare in public?

Comment: or better if you send me the project for it :) will really appreciated

Comment: with a .Copy command pls sir :( ill accept it if you can do it ... really in need :((( @ispiro

Comment: @Elegiac I'm sorry, but I can't send you a project (at least not right now) but if it isn't public - make it public by clicking (in the properties window) next to "modifiers".